# Set and Scroll to SelectedIndex of ListBox in Pivot in WP10

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to bind `SelectedIndex` of `ListBox` inside Pivot. Headers, Items are bind correctly, however, the `ListBox` `SelectedIndex` is somehow not working.

XAML

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <local:ChapterMenuViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
<Pivot x:Name="pvMain" TitleTemplate="{StaticResource PivotTitleTemplate}"
  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PivotHeaderTemplate}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding ChapterMenuHeader}" SelectionChanged="pvMain_SelectionChanged">
  <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
      <ListBox FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontFamily="./Fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf#Scheherazade" 
       x:Name="lsbChapter" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChapterItemTemplate}"
       SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedChapterIndex}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}">
      </ListBox>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

MVVM

```
public class ChapterMenuViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<ChapterMenusHeader> _chapterMenuHeader;
        DataSource ds = null;
        public ChapterMenuViewModel()
        {
            ChapterMenuHeader = new ObservableCollection<ChapterMenusHeader>();
            ds = new DataSource();

            List<JuzDetail> allJuz = DataSource.GetAllJuz;
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "chapter", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapter, Juzs = allJuz });
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "location", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapterSortedByChapterType, Juzs = allJuz });
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "order", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapterSortedByOrder, Juzs = allJuz });
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "size", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapterSortedBySize, Juzs = allJuz });
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "arabic name", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapterSortedByArabicAlphabet, Juzs = allJuz });
            ChapterMenuHeader.Add(new ChapterMenusHeader() { Header = "english name", Chapters = DataSource.GetAllChapterSortedByEnglishAlphabet, Juzs = allJuz });
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ChapterMenusHeader> ChapterMenuHeader
        {
            get { return _chapterMenuHeader; }
            set
            {
                if (_chapterMenuHeader != value)
                {
                    _chapterMenuHeader = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ChapterMenuHeader");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public class ChapterMenusHeader : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            public ChapterMenusHeader()
            {
                SelectedChapterIndex = App.Recent.ChapterID;
            }
            string _header;
            public string Header
            {
                get { return _header; }
                set
                {
                    if (_header != value)
                    {
                        _header = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Header");
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Chapter> _allChapters;
            public List<Chapter> Chapters
            {
                get { return _allChapters; }
                set
                {
                    if (_allChapters != value)
                    {
                        _allChapters = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Chapters");
                    }
                }
            }

            int _selectedChapterIndex;
            public int SelectedChapterIndex
            {
                get { return _selectedChapterIndex; }
                set
                {
                    _selectedChapterIndex = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChapterIndex");
                }
            }
            List<JuzDetail> allJuz;
            public List<JuzDetail> Juzs
            {
                get { return allJuz; }
                set
                {
                    if (allJuz != value)
                    {
                        allJuz = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Juzs");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Scrolling Section

```
private void lsbChapter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   ListBox lsb = sender as ListBox;
   if (lsb.SelectedIndex != -1)
      scrollIntoSelectedItem(lsb, lsb.SelectedIndex);
 }

void scrollIntoSelectedItem(ListBox lsb, int index)
{
   lsb.SelectionChanged -= lsbChapter_SelectionChanged;
   lsb.SelectedIndex = lsb.Items.Count - 1;
   lsb.UpdateLayout();
   lsb.ScrollIntoView(lsb.SelectedIndex);

   lsb.SelectedIndex = index;
   lsb.UpdateLayout();
   lsb.ScrollIntoView(index);

   lsb.SelectionChanged += lsbChapter_SelectionChanged;
}
```

This is only portion of the `ViewModel` class where I am binding the `SelectedIndex` of `ListBox`.
The `ListBox` items are bind correctly, however, the `SelectedIndex` is not working. 
How to set and scroll the `SelectedIndex` of `ListBox` in Pivot?

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help either, I am getting not found error 
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedChapterIndex' property not found on...

Comment: Show me how you defined your ChapterMenuHeader instance.

Comment: I pasted whole MVVM class and XAML as well.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, but don't you need to set `SelectedIndex` binding to two-way?

Comment: I set Mode = two way as well it didn't help. I just need to show the selectedIndex of the listbox, but it's not binding. I am really confused why it doesn't work? I am getting no error nothing at all. The other way around would be, how to get listbox inside pivot?

Comment: You know what, try this, move `ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}"` in front of the `SelectedIndex` binding.

Comment: OMG this did the job. Thanks a lot dear. However, it doesn't scroll to the selectedItem.

Comment: Haha great! I will put this in an answer as it might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out the issue is at this line -

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedChapterIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}"
```

You need to move the `ItemsSource` binding in front of the `SelectedIndex` one -

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedChapterIndex}"
```

The reason? I suspect that it's because of the instantiation sequence of the two values. When the `SelectedIndex` is placed in front of the `ItemsSource` in  xaml and assigned with a value in the constructor, the `ItemsSource` is still `null`, so nothing will be selected.

Now, to scroll to a particular item, you need to call the `ScrollIntoView` method on the `ListBox`. In your case, it should be

```
lsbChapter.ScrollIntoView(Chapters[SelectedChapterIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks! would you please let me where to call this?

Comment: Subscribe to `SelectionChanged` and then when the `SelectedIndex` is not `-1`, do this?

Comment: I have added the scroll section, but it doesn't work. I also paste the code above

Comment: `ScrollIntoView` takes an `object`, NOT `int`. See my answer above? You need to pass in the actual item which is `lsb.ScrollIntoView(lsb.Items[index]);` in your case. Or simply `lsb.ScrollIntoView(lsb.SelectedItem);`